# Somar as diagonais de uma matriz

Tags: c, matriz

Preciso fazer um programa que some as diagonais de uma matriz.
Conforme o exemplo 
[image: exemplo]

Mas estou tendo muita dificuldade.
Segue código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define M 4
#define N 3
int main(){
    int i, j, soma=0;
    int mat[M][N]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}, result[M+N-1];

    for(i=0; i<M+N-1; i++){ //deixar todos valores do vetor iguais a zero
        result=0;
    }

    int a, b, k=0, aux; //auxiliares

    for(i=M-1; i>=0; i--){
        for(j=N-1; j>=0; j--){
            result[k]=mat[j];   //posição 0 do vetor recebe posição 4x3 da matriz;
                a=i;
                b=j;
                while(a>=0 && b<N && b>=0){   //verificar se linha>=0, coluna<N e >=0
                    a--;  //decrementa linha
                    b++;  //acrescenta coluna
                    result[k]+=mat[a]; //valor da posição 0 do vetor soma com o proximo valo da diagonal superior direita
                }
            k++; //avança para proxima posição do vetor*/
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        for(j=0; j<N; j++){
            printf("\t%d   ", mat[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<M+N-1; i++){
        printf("%d   ", result);
    }
}
```

A principio estou tentando fazer só a soma das diagonais pra depois usar as threads para realizar os processos. 
Alguem poderia me ajudar?
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: A lógica é bem simples: considerando os elementos na linha `i` e coluna `j`, basta você somar todos os que a soma de `i+j` seja `z`, sendo `z` a linha da matriz resultado. Em outras palavras: `r[0]` será a soma de todos os elementos cujo `i+j` é 0, ou seja, `mat[0][0]`; `r[1]` será a soma de todos os elementos cujo `i+j` é 1, ou seja, `mat[0][1]+mat[1][0]`; assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score 2):

> Solução apenas implementando a lógica das somas, como requerido, sem trabalhar com *threads*.

A lógica, como comentei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199563/somar-as-diagonais-de-uma-matriz#comment409621_199563), para definir as diagonais secundárias é verificar a soma entre a posição da linha e da coluna do elemento. Por exemplo, considere a matriz genérica abaixo:

```
    [ a00 a01 a02 ]
A = [ a10 a11 a12 ]
    [ a20 a21 a22 ]
    [ a30 a31 a32 ]
```

Aplicando a soma das diagonais secundárias, armazenando a soma em uma matriz `resultado`, temos:

```
resultado[0] = a00
resultado[1] = a10 + a01
resultado[2] = a20 + a11 + a02
resultado[3] = a30 + a21 + a12 + a03
resultado[4] = a31 + a22
resultado[5] = a32
```

Percebe que a soma de `i` e `j` sempre resulta na posição da matriz `resultado`? Isto é, para `resultado[0]` a soma `i+j` sempre é 0, para `resultado[1]` a soma `i+j` sempre é 1, assim sucessivamente. Portanto, o código ficaria algo como:

```
#define M 4
#define N 3
#define Z M+N-1

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    int mat[M][N] = {
        { 1,  2,  3},
        { 4,  5,  6},
        { 7,  8,  9},
        {10, 11, 12}
    };

    int result[Z] = {0};

    // z varia de 0 a M+N-1, exclusive
    // Indica a linha na matriz resultados:
    for (int z = 0; z < Z; z++) {

        // i varia de 0 a M, exclusive
        // Indica a linha na matriz mat:
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {

            // j varia de 0 a N, exclusive
            // Indica a coluna na matriz mat:
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

                // Se a soma da posição for igual a z:
                if (i + j == z) {

                    // Incrementa a soma:
                    result[z] += mat[i][j];

                }

            }

        }

        // Exibe o resultado da soma:
        printf("%2d\n", result[z]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ao executar o código, a saída será:

```
 1
 6
15
24
20
12
```

> **Nota**: A imagem da pergunta traz o resultado errado na quarta linha, pois a soma deveria ser `10+8+6` e foi feito `10+9+6`.

Para implementar a lógica com *threads*, ao invés de você iterar sobre o valor de `z`, você cria as `T` *threads*, em que cada uma é responsável por calcular uma determinada posição do resultado. Inclusive você poderia definir uma função para calcular uma diagonal específica:

```
int sum(int z, int mat[M][N]) {

    int result = 0;

    // i varia de 0 a M, exclusive
    // Indica a linha na matriz mat:
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {

        // j varia de 0 a N, exclusive
        // Indica a coluna na matriz mat:
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

            // Se a soma da posição for igual a z:
            if (i + j == z) {

                // Incrementa a soma:
                result += mat[i][j];

            }

        }

    }

    return result;

}
```

E efetuar as chamadas de `result[0] = sum(0, mat)`, `result[1] = sum(1, mat)`, ..., nas *threads*.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/AHoswV).

Comment: Acho que você esqueceu do link

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Corrigido, obrigado.